# Checking if a jQuery selector doesn't find any results

Tags: jquery

I'm used to Prototypejs, where $$("selector") will return null if no elements were found. This is convenient because I can do

```
if ($$("selector")) {}
```

to check if an element is in the DOM.

However, in jQuery $(selector) will return [] if no element is found, so now I need to do:

```
if ( $(selector).length > 0 )
```

This makes code slightly harder to read.

My question: What's the best way of doing this? Should I extend the jQuery object with methods like .empty() and .any(), or are there built in functions to do this?

Update: This also applies to other selectors on jQuery which should, anyways, only return one result (like parent(), or closest())

Comment: You only need to do `if ($(selector).length)` since it seems the `0` is falsey...

Comment: Get rid of the `> 0` predicate. It is redundant.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
$.fn.exists = function () {
    return this.length !== 0;
}
```

Used like:

```
$("#notAnElement").exists();
```

Comment: idk if it's faster or if it matters, but you could use `$.fn.exists = function () { return !!this[0]; }` too

Answer (score 25):

Using `length` is the best way. You shouldn't use `empty()` or `size() > 0` since that just adds another entry to the call stack.

Comment: Using if ($(select).length) works quite well, I forgot that I could omit the > 0!

Answer (score 13):

```
if ( $(selector)[0] )
```

That'll do it.